# How to rename an Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Is there a way to rename an oracle procedure, without having to drop and recreate the procedure?

Comment: Can I ask why you don't want to do a drop and re-create?

Comment: because i'd have to create the fixes and the grants for all of them, and since i'm making tests, i have a lot of procedures to modify.

Answer (score 7):

UNfortunately there is no equivalent of `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME` TO for PL/SQL objects.  So I'm afraid you will have to drop the procedure and create it afresh with the new name....

... unless using a SYNONYM will resolve your bind. Without knowing *why* you want to change the procedure name it's a bit difficult to give advice.

Answer (score 3):

A way around this would be using a procedure inside a package. Then you might use `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ...` and `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ...` to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to rename a procedure unless you drop and create it again. Anyway:

- If you have a lot of procedures you'd have to use `PACKAGE`s instead of `PROCEDURE`s. In this way you'd only need to change the `PACKAGE BODY`.
- If your problem is to recreate the grants you can create easily an script to do it querying `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` (yes, also contains privileges for procedures).

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively rename a Procedure by simply creating another procedure - with the new name - that simply calls the old procedure

> create or replace procedure **new_procedure_name**
>   as
>   begin
>
> **old_procedure_name;**
>
> end;

Comment: This creates only confusion for future editors. If you really want to call a procedure with different names, use synonyms.