# Renaming a Stored Procedure which is in a package in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, rename

I have a SP in a package in Oracle 10g. I use Oracle SQL Developer to access the Dbs. How can I rename this SP? One of the solutions is the following command.

```
create or replace procedure new_procedure_name
as
begin 
old_procedure_name; 
end;
```

This was a solution I found on StackOverflow ([old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221202/how-to-rename-an-oracle-procedure)). Also many people suggested that we need to drop and create a new SP. My stuff is in a package and I dont think the above command works there.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. Suggestion accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ben and @AlejoBrz for taking time to answer my question. This is what a more experienced developer who helped me did. Just go to the package, right click it and compile it, then rename the SP under the Pckg_body to another name, rename the SP  under the package, recompile and the name is changed. @AlejoBrz, I was not aware that there is a PCKG and a PCKG_BODy, so I was lost as to why upon right click, I dont get the drop/create option. It occurs only for PCKG and not PCKG_body.

Answer (score 3):

What you've posted:

```
create or replace procedure new_procedure_name as
begin 
old_procedure_name; 
end;
```

is a valid way to do this. However, it is only going to cause you problems. There's no obvious linkage between `old_procedure_name` and `new_procedure_name` ( though there obviously is the other way round ).

Better by far is to find the place where your package / procedure is stored on your version control system. Change the name, commit it and then recompile the package.

This applies whether it is a stand-alone function / procedure or one inside a package.

A re-compile is effectively a "drop" as you have to replace the current version with the new one, i.e. I completely agree with your linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to open the package, change the name of the procedure, and recompile. When you open it it should say

```
create or replace package ...
```

(as oposed to create or replace procedure)

Comment: well..what I have is a package with about 10 SPs in it and each of the SP has around 2000 lines of code. Moreoever, how can I create or replace it. I use SQL Developer and I did not see any command either in the menu or if I right click the package. Can you pls elaborate? Thanks

Comment: @Raghu I haven't use SQL Developer especifically, but the IDE I used you just navigated through all packages, selected one, right clicked on it, and it would open as "create or replace package [packageName]". Then you go to your procedure, rename it, and compile the whole package. After that, you should make sure no other packages were invalidated, and recompile them if so. This this help?